# React Three Fiber: How do I change the camera angle?

Tags: react-three-fiber

Currently I have a `PerspectiveCamera` set up like so:

```
<Canvas>
  <PerspectiveCamera
    makeDefault
    fov={50}
    position={[0, 0, 80]}
  />
</Canvas>
```

It seems to be pointing straight into the `z` direction. I would like the camera to point straight down in the negative `y` direction. How can I change the angle that it points at?

Comment: rotation={[Math.Pi/2,0,0]} or -Math.Pi/2

Comment: That works! could you add an answer so I can make it accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rotation attribute to the camera same as you added position.

```
<Canvas>
  <PerspectiveCamera
    makeDefault
    fov={50}
    position={[0, 0, 80]}
    rotation={[x, y, z]}
  />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is missing explanation, exactly why rotation is applied on X axes, why it’s Math.Pi / 2, and obviously few words what is camera in general